# Why does BinarySearch use ~ operator to return a negative number?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, binary-search

In [this code](https://github.com/ayende/phonebook/blob/31295ee03ecb18d01ff2cc8caa577d53b52740e0/Phobebook.cs), there is a binary-search algorithm. To signal that the item is not found, a negative number is returned, which in the code is done with `return ~mid` (see [line 92](https://github.com/ayende/phonebook/blob/31295ee03ecb18d01ff2cc8caa577d53b52740e0/Phobebook.cs#L92)).

```cs
public int Search(string name)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = _sortedPositions.Count - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) >> 1;
        _stream.Position = _sortedPositions[mid];
        var curName = _br.ReadString();
        var comp = string.Compare(name, curName);
        if (comp == 0)
            return mid;
        if (comp < 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    return ~mid;
}
```

My question is: why is it done like this? Is there any advantage over returning a fixed negative int, like `return -1`?

Comment: If you need help with a specific issue, post all relevant code in your question; not links to code.

Comment: _"Is there any advantage over returning a fixed negative int"_ -- it's a convenient way to report both that the desired element isn't present while still also providing the index of where it would have been. See e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_BinarySearch__0_.

Comment: I was going to answer your question, but it was closed. The answer is yes, there is an advantage. If you have the bitwise complement of where the record *would* be found, you can undo the bitwise complement with `~` and find the insertion index for the record that you were searching for in case you need to add a record to the list that you were searching.

Comment: @Codexer you may have not needed to think about this for awhile, but casting reopen/close votes requires 3000 reputation https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: You're correct, it has been a while.

Comment: .NET does the same https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/c6af4cfc8b625851b91823d9be746c4f7abdc667/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Array.cs#L512

Comment: Note that this function has a bug, so it returns the incorrect negative value for lots of cases. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I have reported it to the repository author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a benefit *(if the function returns the correct value, which it does not, see more below)*.

The negative number indicates that the key that was searched for was not found in the collection, **just as returning -1 would**.

However, what you gain, compared to simply returning -1, is that you can flip the bits of this negative value once again to get back the index where the value *ought to be* if it were to follow the sort order.

You could use it like this:

```
int index = Search("Some name");
if (index < 0)
    // insert at position (~index)
```

---

Now, this particular search function has a flaw in which it will incorrectly report the wrong index in a boundary case where it has found the last item to compare to, but the name it searches for should be *after* this item.

As an example, try adding the following two strings in the positions reported by the Search function: `A` and then `Z`.

It will add them in the wrong order, `Z` before `A`.

The reason for this is that it found the single item `A` that it should compare against at index 0, but `Z` should be added *after* index 0, not *at* index 0.

However, the fix for this bug is simple:

1. Move the initial calculation of `mid` outside of the loop
2. ... and do the recalculation inside the loop after changing `low` or `high`

This way the final `mid` value will be correct. Here's the final function:

```
public int Search(string name)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = _sortedPositions.Count - 1;
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;                  // note #2
    while (low <= high)
    {
        var curName = _sortedPositions[mid];           // note #1
        var comp = string.Compare(name, curName);
        if (comp == 0)
            return mid;
        if (comp < 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;                  // note #2
    }
    return ~mid;
}
```

*(note #1: I switched `sortedPositions` to a simple `List<string>` while I was spelunking with your code to make it run. Obviously this will be different for your stream based example.)*

*(note #2: The way I calculate the `mid` value, by calculating the difference and dividing by 2, is the suggested way to do this. If the collection has so many values that `low + high` will overflow, the suggested way will not.)*

A simpler fix, employed by many implementations, is that at the point where you have no more items to look at, `low == mid` (with the above change), so a different fix for the bug would be to return `~low` instead of `~mid`, and then minimal changes have to be performed:

```
public int Search(string name)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = _sortedPositions.Count - 1;
    int mid;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;                  // note #2
        var curName = _sortedPositions[mid];           // note #1
        var comp = string.Compare(name, curName);
        if (comp == 0)
            return mid;
        if (comp < 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    return ~low;
}
```

Comment: Not only the fix #2 avoids a bug, but also makes the code much clearer IMHO. BTW, i wanted to verify the fix with my own eyes, here is some fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lu4BTk

Comment: Indeed, `return ~lo` is what .NET code does